# What set does this bag belong to? Mostly black with some red and yellow pieces

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Bought these at a garage sale.  [image]
Picture of bag.  5.  121r8

Answer (score 7):

I can see a [Black Wedge, Plate A-Shape with 2 Rows of 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15706) and a [Dark Red Wedge, Plate 4 x 2 Left](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41770). Those appear just in two sets, and I'm fairly convinced that you've got parts of Ninjago set [70653-1 Firstbourne](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70653-1):

[image: Set 70653-1 "Firstbourne"]

The [inventory of that set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70653-1) is consistent with other parts seen your photograph - there's [Wedge, Plate 3 x 2 Left](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43723) in Bright Light Orange (easily mistaken with Yellow), [Dark Bluish Gray 1x2 Technic Brick 1 x 2 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32000), barbs in Bright Orange, and others.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts

Comment: I was mistaken! There's like 5 shades of yellow, and since the lighting and white balance of your photograph is... not the best, I was fooled by the *bright light orange* colour.

Comment: Set 70653 is also consistent with the note written on the bag that 2x [part 35633](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35633) was taken out of the bag. And there's 6 of those in that set (in Black).